# Taylor Series for solving ODE

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Solve for $x$ and $y$.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x+y+t, \frac{dy}{dt}=2x-t \quad given  ,x=0, y=1 \quad at \quad t=1$$

This is given in the Taylor series method of solving differential equaition. In my limited knowledge, i know how to solve such type of questions when particular values are given i.e. we take small increments and write the taylor series expansion around that point .
Any help is appreciated .Thanks.

**Edited** : The answer given is $$x=2t + t^2 + \frac {5}{6} t^3 +...$$
$$y = 1-t + \frac{3}{2}t^2 + \frac{2}{3} t^3$$

Comment: What you describe sounds very similar to me to [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), is that what you mean?

Comment: Euler's method fall in the same basket of methods for solving ODEs. However , writing taylor series , i guess , is a common practice.

Comment: Okay, in that case do you have a final value for $t$ you want to stop at? We need some ending point if we're going to simulate it like that. (there are also ways to solve analytically)

Comment: The answer is given in a series form . However , i am sceptical of what it really means .

Comment: Okay, can you show the answer you're given? I think that would help a lot

Comment: @StephenDonovan edited to add answer

Comment: Okay, my apologies I've had something entirely different in mind this entire time. I can start working on that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the derivatives at $t=1$ step-by-step, as
\begin{align}
x''&=x'+y'+1,& y''&=2x'-1,\\
x'''&=x''+y'',& y'''&=2x'',
\end{align}
and so on. Then insert into the Taylor formulas for $x$ and $y$.
So
\begin{align}
x(1)&=0,& y(1)&=1,\\
x'(1)&=2,& y'(1)&=-1,\\
x''(1)&=2,& y''(1)&=3,\\
x'''(1)&=5,& y'''(1)&=4,
\end{align}
giving
$$
x(t)=2(t-1)+(t-1)^2+\frac{5}{6}(t-1)^3+...\\
y(t)=1-(t-1)+\frac32(t-1)^2+\frac23(t-1)^3+...
$$
so the reference solution would be correct as $x(1+t)$ and $y(1+t)$.

Comment: In the taylor series expansion , should we not measure increment by $t-1$ and not $t$ ?The answer comes when $t$ is substituted in taylor series expansion.

Comment: Yes and yes. In my answer I just needed to change a number, and the reference solution should indeed be in powers of $(t-1)$. One can expand this if one gives a remainder term $O((t-1)^{p+1})$.

Comment: The expansion using $t-1$doesn't match the answer. I guess the answer is wrong then as it uses $t$ instead of $t-1$

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Shouldn't it be $$x(t)=2(t-1)+(t-1)^2+\dfrac{5}{6}(t-1)^3+...$$

Comment: @Moo : Yes, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann for answering

Answer (score 1):

Make your life simpler
$$x'=x+y+t \implies x''=x'+y'+1$$ Now use $$y'=2x-t $$ to make
$$x''=x'+2x-t+1$$ Make the series for $x$ and when done, use $y=x'-x-t$